# Cross Browser date input support

Tags: html, date, cross-browser

I have a basic LAMP setup for storing order information.

I am running into problems when presenting dates for editing.

Briefly a date is entered on an HTML form which on submission is stored in a database. I can retrieve the date and present it without issue in IE 11 and Firefox ESR 52.2. If I use Edge or Chrome 58.0.3029.110 the date is replaced by a dd/mm/yyyy placeholder. Which I understand is by design. The code I'm using is pretty straightforward.

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
```

What I am looking for is a way of doing this which is supported on IE 11, Edge and Chrome. What I have seen so far implies it isn't possible to have it behave correctly across all modern browsers (yes, I know IE 11 could barely be described as modern but if you are on Windows 7 this is the latest Microsoft have to offer).

Comment: The browser cannot see your PHP code. What does `<?php echo $date; ?>` render? If you are unsure, you can normally hit Ctrl+U to find out.

Comment: '<input type="date" value="18-07-2017" />'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok more of a work around than an answer. From what I am reading this is apparently impossible although I still find that difficult to believe.

I changed my input types to text and used a datepicker to ensure dates were entered in a standard format.